# VB.net Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement (Although, there's not syntax error in the statment)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have tested this SQL statement in Microsoft Access and it work perfectly but for some reason it doesn't work in my code. I have checked it many times and I haven't figure out the syntax error (Although, it work in MS Access).

Here's the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Now, when the Register button is clicked,
    'We check, if the user type is User, we create a normal User in the database.
    'Otherwise, we create a Wroker.

    Dim fname, lname, nationality, password As String
    Dim age, yearExpr, phone, saloonID, type As Integer

    fname = fNameBox.Text
    lname = LNameBox.Text
    age = Convert.ToInt32(ageBox.Text)
    phone = Convert.ToInt32(phoneBox.Text)
    password = passwordBox.Text


    If (userTypeCB.Text.Equals("User")) Then
        type = 1
        salSql = ""
        salCnc.Open()
        salSql = "INSERT INTO User ([Fname], [Lname], [Age], [Phone#], [Type], [Password])
                 VALUES (" & "'" & fname & "'" & "," & "'" & lname & "'" & "," & age & "," & phone & "," & type & "," & "'" & password & "'" & ")"


        salCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(salSql, salCnc)
        salCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        salCnc.Close()



    ElseIf (userTypeCB.Text.Equals("Worker")) Then
        yearExpr = exprBox.Text
        saloonID = saloonBox.Text
        nationality = NationBox.Text

    End If
End Sub
```

Now, the compiler points to the `salCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` as the error source. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Error explains that you have a syntax error in the insert statement. Also you should used parameterized command to avoid SQL injection which could also be the cause of this syntac error

Comment: What data types are `Age`, `Phone#` and `Type`? I'd strongly recommend using command parameters to avoid SQL Injection attack vulnerability.

Comment: ... or [Moms Will Pwn Your App](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Nkosi I'm new to visual basic and this the way I learned how to write SQL commands in VB.net. Even my instructor in the college write them like this *_*

Comment: @Filburt `Age`, `Phone#` and `Type` are of type Number in the database. I'm using MS Access database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to @LarsTech

> User is a keyword. You have to put it in brackets. ie: `INSERT INTO [User]...`

Also, use a parameterized command to avoid SQL injection which could also be the cause of this syntax error.

```
'''code removed for brevity

salSql = "INSERT INTO [User] ([Fname],[Lname],[Age],[Phone#],[Type],[Password]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"


salCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(salSql, salCnc)

salCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", fname)
salCommand.Parameters.Add("@lname", lname)
salCommand.Parameters.Add("@age", age)
salCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", phone)
salCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", type)
salCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", password)

salCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

'''code removed for brevity
```

Comment: I have just tested your solution and it doesn't work. It shows the exact same error and points to the exact same line, which is `salCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @AbbasAleid `INSERT INTO [User]...`

Comment: User is a keyword.  You have to put it in brackets.

Comment: @LarsTech woow, that was really the problem. This single error wasted hours of my time. I guess this is how you waste your time when you become a developer.

Comment: Yes.  OleDB would just convert @phone into a ? behind the scenes anyway.  Parameters just have to match their index order correctly.